# Passenger/Apache missing gcc/zlib-devel on AWS/CENTOS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, centos, passenger

I am trying to install Passenger for Apache on an AWS instance running CENTOS.  When I try to install it, it tells me:

```
GNU C++ compiler... not found
Zlib development headers... not found
```

These have both been installed (yum install gcc zlib-devel) and are at the latest version.  gcc -v says that it's at 4.6.2.

I have seen similar questions where the accepted answer was to run

```
mount -o remount,rw,exec,nosuid /tmp
```

This returns the following:

```
mount: can't find /tmp in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

I have tried changing the permissions on the /tmp directory (it does exist, just doesn't appear to be mounted) with chmod 777 /tmp, but this did not allow the Passenger install to see the two packages.

Could someone please help me with this?  I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I installed Ruby through RVM, as that likely matters.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the issue above, but I managed to install anyway by adding EPEL, then installing mod_passenger through yum:

```
rpm -Uvh http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install mod_passenger
```